# Suppressing Blank lines in "If..then...else" word mail merger

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge, blank-line

I am trying to send out a mass mail merge email to clients who are in an accreditation process. I am using an Excel spreadsheet in the merger, and in the datasheet if the client has taken a  class I indicate it with the number of credit hours (so they can also be added up as part of the letter). However since I want the class name rather than the number of credits it is worth I used the "if...then...else.." field. So that if the credit number is greater than 0 than the Class Name is inserted or else it is blank. My Merge field therefore looks like this:

```
{ IF { MERGEFIELD M_2713_CLASS } = 6 "Class Name" ""}
```

Where the "6" is the number of credits. There are about 40 classes entered as a list (one below the other). The problem I am running into is getting the classes that the client has not taken and are therefore blank to not show up as a blank line. I am not a programmer by any meaning of the word but I know there is a way to do it, I just can't seem to figure out even with the help of Google. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The traditional approach is along the following lines:

```
{ IF { MERGEFIELD M_2713_CLASS } = 6 "Class Name A
" }{ IF { MERGEFIELD M_2713_CLASS } = 7 "Class Name B
" }{ IF { MERGEFIELD M_2713_CLASS } = 8 "Class Name C
" }etc.
```

I.e. You press Enter to insert a paragraph mark inside the IF field, at the end of the text you want to insert., instead of outside the IF field.